# How to tell the GNU assembler to warn when using undefined labels?

Tags: assembly, x86, bootloader, gnu-assembler, osdev

**Is there any way to tell the GNU assembler to warn on using undefined labels on compilation time?**

Let's suppose I made a typo:

```
jmp MyLabell

MyLabel:
```

I don't use a linker. I use `as` to generate an object file, and then I `objcopy` to convert the `.o` file to a raw binary. I do this because I intend to run it in an environment that can only execute raw binaries (a real mode bootloader). I thought the assembler would warn me if I used an undefined label when assembling the source code

It will compile just fine, but since `MyLabell` was never defined, it will always translate to address `0`, leaving the programmer clueless and oblivious. **Can `as` be told not to ignore such problems?** If not, is there a reason it's not possible? As far as I can remember (correct me if I'm wrong), NASM does care that I use *only* defined labels.

Version of the GNU assembler I am using: **GNU assembler (GNU Binutils) 2.29.1**

I've already spent a whole night debugging my code just to find out that after renaming a label, I did not change all references to it.

Comment: When you link it should have told you it was undefined. GNU assembler will assume that any label it doesn't see in the current file exists in another file. That leaves it to the link process (`ld` or `gcc` can be used for linking) to determine if there was an undefined reference when it pulls all the objects together.

Comment: I don't use a linker. I only `objcopy` it to a raw binary because I run it in an environment that can only execute raw binaries. I thought `as` could warn me that I used an undefined label when compiling the source code.

Comment: Then you are doing it wrong. Sounds like your are doing OS Development of some sort. You can assemble files (or compile) to multiple object files, generate a freestanding executable with a linker and then use `objcopy` to convert that fully linked executable to binary form so that it can be used easily in a bare metal environment. The fact you are converting raw object files tells me you are are already on the wrong path.

Comment: What OS are you doing this on Windows (with either Cygwin or MinGW's `gcc`? Linux? MacOS (OS/X)?

Comment: @JulSe Even then you should use the linker.  The GNU assembler does produces object files with relocations left to be filled in. You must use a linker.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I'm doing this on Linux Mint 18.2.  And yes, I'm experimenting a little bit with OS development. Can I use the linker with only one input file just to do this kind of symbol checking?

Comment: @JulSe Yes. You should also write your own linker script.  In this script you can setup things such as predefined symbols and the address your binary is loaded at.

Comment: @JulSe The GNU assembler is meant to be used with a linker. It doesn't make a lot of sense at all to use it without one. It's a futile, painful exercise.

Comment: Yes as Fuz says. One object file or 1,000+ object files you can still use the linker. Without the linker I'd be curious how you set the origin point for the code as well.

Comment: Are you writing a real mode bootloader (loaded by a legacy BIOS at physical address 0x07c00), or a protected mode one (via something like a Multibootload like GRUB)?

Comment: @MichaelPetch Probably a misunderstood `.org` directive. Hint: In the GNU assembler, `.org` doesn't do what you might think it does.

Comment: Thanks, that totally makes sense now! I'm using the linker for my kernel but the stage 2 loader is a raw binary so I thought that I didn't have to use a linker for that. If you wish, you can post this as an answer and I will accept it if it works :)

Comment: @fuz I thought that `.org` in 16-bit mode sets the offset that the file is loaded at in a segment. I set it to `0` and segments registers to where it was actually loaded.

Comment: @JulSe No. It just inserts enough zeroes so the offset in the current section is that address. It's usually not the right directive to use.

Comment: @JulSe This is pretty useless on its own because sections from all files are merged into one binary during linking.  It's only useful for makeshift use cases like yours, but even there it somewhat fails.  It's a rudiment from old times.

Comment: I was hoping that `.L` local labels would give a warning, but no, you still get an undefined reference to `.LMyLabel`, even though `.LMyLabell` doesn't appear in the symbol table.  You could produce an object file that defined `.LMyLabel`, but not directly with `as`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is in essence an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/271768).

To answer the original question GNU Assembler `as` assumes that any label that it can't find in the current file is in another file that will be resolved by a linker at link time. It places a dummy value as the jump target that is resolved by the linker.

---

The issue comes down to the fact that you never found out if the label was undefined because you didn't run it through a linker to generate an executable. Converting a raw object file to a flat binary may not work as expected. To fix this:

- Use the GNU assembler to generate an object file(s).
- Use the linker LD to set the origin point
- Use OBJCOPY to convert the final linked executable to binary.

---

If you are creating a real mode bootloader, do not use the `.org` directive in GNU Assembler. It doesn't do what you expect it to. This is different that the `org` directive that NASM uses when generating raw binary files directly. You could use something like:

```
as --32 boot.s -o boot.o
ld -melf_i386 -nostdlib -Ttext=0x7c00 boot.o -o boot.elf
objcopy -O binary boot.elf boot.bin
```

With the *LD* command in the example you can specify any number of `.o` files to link together or just one object file if you wish.

---

As an addendum to the last section I prefer to use a linker script with LD. For bootloaders I use the linker to place the boot signature in the appropriate place (it can be removed from your assembly file), and sets the origin point to 0x7c00. This is a very simple one that assumes your bootloader only uses a `.text`, `.data` or even an `.rodata` section:

File `link.ld`:

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT("elf32-i386");
ENTRY(start);
SECTIONS
{
    . = 0x7C00;
    .text : {
        *(.text);
    }
    .data : {
        *(.data);
        *(.rodata);
    }

    /* Boot signature */
    .sig : AT(0x7DFE) {
        SHORT(0xaa55);
    }

    /* Discard common unwanted/unneeded sections */
    /DISCARD/ : {
        *(.comment);
        *(.note.gnu.build-id);
    }
}
```

Then assemble and link the file. In this case we specify `-Tlink.ld` to use the linker script above, and we no longer have to use `-Ttext=0x7c00`:

```
as --32 boot.s -o boot.o
ld -melf_i386 -nostdlib -Tlink.ld boot.o -o boot.elf
objcopy -O binary boot.elf boot.bin
```

---

Properly using a linker to generate executables should produce an error similar to this if a label like `MyLabel1` was not found:

> boot.o:(.text+0x1): undefined reference to `MyLabell'

---

### Origin points and Real Mode code

The GNU Linker has no understanding of [real mode 20-bit segment:offset addressing](http://thestarman.pcministry.com/asm/debug/Segments.html). A bootloader will be loaded at physical address 0x07c00, but there is more than one way to address that location. In real mode segment:offset addressing the segment and the offset combine to define the physical address. The calculation is segment * 16 + offset. The origin point you choose in the linker script or the `.Ttext=` option must combine with the segment you load into the segment registers (especially *DS*) to be 0x07c00. If you set the segments to 0x0000 then the offset you need is 0x7c00 because 0x0000 * 16 + 0x7c00 = 0x07c00. Using a segment of 0x7c0 you'd need an offset of 0x0000 as 0x7c0 * 16 + 0x0000 = 0x07c00.

My linker script `link.ld` assumed you loaded the *DS* segment register with 0x0000. The value you used for the segments was 0x7c0 so you need to change the `link.ld` to use `. = 0x0000;` instead of `. = 0x7C00;`.

If you use `. = 0x0000` as an origin point then you also need to adjust the bootloader location by subtracting 0x7c00 from it. The line `.sig : AT(0x7DFE) {` would have to be changed to `.sig : AT(0x1FE) {`.If you don't use a linker script and specify the origin point when running LD then it would have to be changed to `-Ttext=0x0000`.

Comment: @JulSe : no problem. I have also amended the answer to include a linker script that can be used to place the boot signature where you need it in the file (you can then remove the assembly directives from your `.s` that place the boot signature.

Comment: I am now playing around with the linker script for my bootloader and stage 2 loader and I found your code for the linker script very useful. However, it only works if I set the offset in the linker script to `. = 0` (with `.org 0`). I tried offsets `0x07C0`, `0x7C00` and `0x2000` (for my stage 2 loader) but they don't work (the loaders malfunction). It works with `. = 0` however, wonder why is that...

Comment: I may have jumped the gun. The starting point (ORG) will be relative to the segment you intend to use in the assembly code. If your code sets the _DS_ register to 0x07c0 then you need to use an origin point of 0x0 rather than 0x7c00. Since you didn't post your bootloader code I made a guess that may have been wrong. The segment value you use mutlipled by 16(decimal) + offset needs to be 0x07c00. I'm guessing in your code you are doing something similar to `mov ax, 0x7c0` `mov ds, ax`? 0x07c0 * 16 + 0x0000 = 0x7c00.

Comment: That's exactly the case, I set DS to `0x07C0` in my bootloader. Thank you :)

Comment: Yep, my bad. Many people set the segments to 0x0000 and the offset to 0x7c00. 0x0000 * 16 + 0x7c00 = physical address 0x07c00 too. sorry about that.

Comment: I have amended my answer with some additional information. I recommend you take a look at it because you'll also have to adjust the boot signature address as well if you want to use a linker script and a segment value of 0x7c0.

Answer (score 2):

The GNU assembler produces an *object file.* Such a file cannot directly be used as a binary, it must be *linked* first, even if there is nothing else to link it to.  The linking process resolves relocations and fixes a loading address for the binary, two tasks the assembler cannot do on its own.  When undefined symbols are left over at the linking stage, the linker complains and aborts the linking process. You can use this behaviour to check for misspelled symbols, something the GNU assembler does not provide on its own because it assumes that every undefined symbol is supplied by another object file during linking.